# Edit and Delete action with Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

i want to update and delete an entry im really new at this and i dont know where to put the function..so yeah i need help

controller

```
function delete()
{
    $this->site_model->delete_row('booking');
    $this->view();
}
}
```

site_model

```
function delete_row()
{
    $this->db->where('id', $this->uri->segment(3));
    $this->db->delete('booking');
}
```

and my view

```
<?php 
$this->table->set_heading("Name","Nationality","Number of Guest","Date","Package","Other      Request","Delete Record");
$qry = $this->db->get('booking');
foreach ($qry->result() as $row) {
$this->table->add_row($row->name,$row->nationality,$row->number_of_guest,$row->date,$row->package,$row->request);

}
echo $this->table->generate();

 ?>
```

TIA, im really new at this so please consider this..

Comment: Is there a question or you just wanted to share this with us?

Comment: This might be able to help you. [Codeigniter CRUD functions](http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/codeigniter-from-scratch-day-5-crud--net-6504) It's an old but good tutorial to get you on your way. Not everything may be up to date but how to instantiate an object and use your functions will not have changed.

Comment: Where to put *what* function?  What's the problem here?

Comment: the delete...how to add a delete button or something like that

Comment: @Shomz i already watched that, that's where i got the codes..but putting it on in a table bugs me, i can't seem to do that

Comment: Have a look at codeigniter's tutorial, it covers database as well http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/tutorial/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have no real question, I'll just give you a few hints before we close this.

- database communication should happen in the model, not the view
- I suggest you use ids instead of uri segments, especially when you're deleting something (see @Wlises' answer)
- to load a view, use `$this->load->view('view_name_here');`
- to create a delete button, you simply need to redirect browser to your delete method of your controller (something like: `site.com/booking/delete/5`, where 5 is the id of the booking) using a simple anchor, JavaScript redirection, form submit, etc...

The bottom line is: **please use the tutorial**, it's very good and covers 99% of what you'd need: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/tutorial/

UPDATE

You can build your own table for more flexibility (and you're probably more comfortable with HTML rather than CI's helper functions). So, every row would need a delete button/link like this:

```
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $row->name; ?></td>
    ... etc
    <td><a href="<?php echo base_url('booking/delete/' . $row->id); ?>">DELETE</a></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: sorry for being a noob..its a question..and i want to add a delete button or something in the view page.. align with the records

Comment: No problem, everyone was a noob at some point, just make sure you be more specific in your questions, that's how this site works. I'll give an example.

Comment: ok thanks..ill wait and here i uploaded it to show what id like to happen or where i would like to put the delete button http://prntscr.com/2vr079

Comment: I've updated my answer right after that comment, see if that works for you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

You can pass parameters through the URL.. so, for example:

yoursite/index.php/controller/delete/12

The ID = 12

In your controller:

```
function delete($id=null)
{
    $this->booking_model->delete($id);
    $this->view('my_view_name');
}
```

booking_model

```
function delete($id)
{
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $this->db->delete('booking');
}
```

Comment: noob question again..but how do i put that in the view.php? so i can delete the rows aligned with it?there's so much noob in me sorry

Comment: An example in your view: 

`<ul>
   <?php foreach($records AS $r) { ?>
    <li>
       <?php echo $r['name'];?>
       <a href="<?php echo site_url('my_controller/delete/'.$r['id']);?>"> Delete</a>
    </li>
   <? } ?>
</ul>`

NOTE: Assuming what you have the $records and 'url_helper' loaded.